# Can't upload tmp file / file uploads won't work

Tags: file-upload, php

I just switched to a dedicated server.  All of the sudden I can't upload files.  My best guess because the tmp file isn't getting uploaded?  Each time I try to do `move_uploaded_file('tmp','new_image');`  I get `permission denied` and `failed to open stream`.

I changed nothing in the script; but the absolute path obviously.  Also, all file permissions are set to 705.  I think it's something to do with the php.ini where the tmp files aren't working...  I no longer have the default php.ini from shared hosting.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  Thank you

Here's my php.ini

```
extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = ./tmp

-- more but not relevant


`Warning: move_uploaded_file(users/126/question_images/question mark.jpeg): failed to open` stream:
```

Here's the permission denied error

`Permission denied in ---.php on line 115 Warning: move_uploaded_file():`

Here's the other error

```
 Unable to move '/tmp/phpVrkytD' to '---.jpeg' in .---.php on line 115
```

Here's the part of the script to upload the image

```
$long_image_loc = 'absolute_path/'.$image_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $long_image_loc) === true) {
                return true;
                }
```

This worked worked perfect on shared hosting.  It's a really straight forward image upload script.

Comment: There are more relevant ini settings that could make a difference, as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php ... perhaps you could also post the part of your code that generates the error?

Comment: Does the folder in which you're trying to move the file exist? That could also cause a permission denied. If it doesn't you can do a recursive `mkdir()`. If the target is fine, the source is likely the issue, so check permissions very carefully.

Comment: In your question you mention " Also, all file permissions are set to 705", but you didn't mention the permissions of the `/tmp` directory itself, if it's not 777 it should be.

Comment: It had to be set to 777 not 755.  Thanks Mike!